# Error: self signed certificate in certificate chain for the tests in the Next.js page tests with next-page-tester

Tags: unit-testing, next.js

I'm looking for a way to overcome the `Error: self signed certificate in certificate chain` for the tests when I try to set up Next.js page tests with [next-page-tester](https://www.npmjs.com/package/next-page-tester).

```
Network Error

      at createError (node_modules/axios/lib/core/createError.js:16:15)
      at XMLHttpRequest.handleError (node_modules/axios/lib/adapters/xhr.js:84:14)
      at XMLHttpRequest.invokeTheCallbackFunction (node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/living/generated/EventHandlerNonNull.js:18:28)
      at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous> (node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/living/helpers/create-event-accessor.js:35:32)        
      at innerInvokeEventListeners (node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/living/events/EventTarget-impl.js:338:25)
      at invokeEventListeners (node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/living/events/EventTarget-impl.js:274:3)
      at XMLHttpRequestImpl._dispatch (node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/living/events/EventTarget-impl.js:221:9)
      at fireAnEvent (node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/living/helpers/events.js:18:36)
      at requestErrorSteps (node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/living/xhr/xhr-utils.js:130:3)
      at Object.dispatchError (node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/living/xhr/xhr-utils.js:59:3)
      at Request.<anonymous> (node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/living/xhr/XMLHttpRequest-impl.js:655:18)
      at Request.onRequestError (node_modules/request/request.js:877:8)

  console.error
    Error: Error: self signed certificate in certificate chain
        at Object.dispatchError (C:\Users\leoniecg\Projects\OneCustomerFrontend\frontend\node_modules\jsdom\lib\jsdom\living\xhr\xhr-utils.js:62:19)
        at Request.<anonymous> (C:\Users\leoniecg\Projects\OneCustomerFrontend\frontend\node_modules\jsdom\lib\jsdom\living\xhr\XMLHttpRequest-impl.js:655:18)
        at Request.emit (events.js:327:22)
        at Request.onRequestError (C:\Users\leoniecg\Projects\OneCustomerFrontend\frontend\node_modules\request\request.js:877:8)
        at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:315:20)
        at TLSSocket.socketErrorListener (_http_client.js:469:9)
        at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:315:20)
        at emitErrorNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:106:8)
        at emitErrorCloseNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:74:3)
        at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:80:21) undefined
```

I have [dotenv](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv) installed, it works ok with the `NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED=0` setting in the development environment, but even if I manage to read **process.env** settings into the test environment, i.e. I can see it with the console.log when I print it at the very top of a test file, I still get the error. Has anyone had this issue? I've been able to read `.env.local` file:

```
//.env.local
NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED=0
```

with the instructions given for example here: [Using dotenv with Jest](https://lusbuab.medium.com/using-dotenv-with-jest-7e735b34e55f).
`NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED=0` setting is a popular one to even start having Next.js on the localhost, so I guess someone has already stumbled upon this.

Or maybe I should forget about next-page-tester and use Cypress?